# Syntax error in visual studio

Tags: python, syntax, error-handling

I started Udacity's Intro to Comp Sci course today, and generated this code at the end of the first lesson:

```
page = '<a href="http://udacity.com">Hello world</a>'
start_link = page.find('<a href=')
start_link = start_link + 9
end_link = page.find(">", start_link)
url = page[start_link:end_link-1]
print url
```

On the web browser interpreter, that code ran fine, but on Visual Studio 2013 I have a syntax error. Can anyone point it out, and let me know why this ran fine on Udacity's interpreter but not on visual studio?

Thanks

Comment: This question is better suited for StackOverflow, and you should specify the **exact** error you are getting.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how Python returns errors, but it mentions line 6, and writes syntax error: invalid syntax.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio has native support for Python (I recall it's available via plugins). Are you sure you're supposed to be using Visual Studio? Have you ensured that Visual Studio has support for Python?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the plugins, and it has been working for other programs, just not this one for some reason.

Comment: You need to be more specific than this.  The only way that I know of to write python in Visual Studio is with IronPython.  Is that how you are doing it?  Meh, we don't really handle Visual Studio syntax errors here anyway.

Comment: I downloaded this: https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/103102

Comment: If your code isn't too long, please paste the whole code along with the exact indentation that you have so we can debug it. Thanks

Comment: I believe your error might be arising from the mixed use of spaces and tabs for indentations. python doesn't like that. Recommended standard by PEP is using 4 spaces for each indentation. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sshashank, that is the whole code. And what do you mean by "mixed use of spaces and tabs for indentations?" I don't have any indentations in this. Also if this helps, when I hover over url in line 6 it says "unexpected token 'url'"